# C# Database Access: Best method to use for getting data

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

The reason I ask, is that origionally all references and examples pointed towards Method 2.

But Method 1 seems to do so much more in so much less code. Surely its

1. neater,
2. Better
3. Easier to read / follow
4. and has features like converting DBNulls to null. Rather than having
   to do it myself.
5. Handles opening and closing of the connection/ data readers.

I cant think of any reasons for method 2 over using method 1.

(Method 2  could probably have a using clause, but due to so much code, it was put in a seperate function to be called from else wher, and hence closing it closed the datareader making data inacccessable.)

Anyway, I am seriously thinking about going back and changing over my entire webservice to use method 1 as it seems so much better and maintainable. Can anyone suggest otherwise?

Method 1:

```
using (var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(Library.Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString, "System.Data.SqlClient"))
        {
            Int32 AccNo = db.QuerySingle("SELECT AccNo FROM Tasks WHERE TaskID = " + TaskID);
        }
```

Method 2:

```
        sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection();
        sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon;

        sqlCon.ConnectionString = global::Library.Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnString;
        sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT AccNo FROM Tasks WHERE TaskID = " + TaskID;
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlDataReader data = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
        while (data.Read())
        {
            Int32 AccNo = (Int32)data["AccNo"];
        }
        sqlCon.Close();
        sqlComm.Dispose();
        if (data != null)
           data.Close();
```

Comment: For both methods, I advice to use parameters with your SqlCommand.

Comment: To prevent sql attacks? I'll look into it thanks :)

Comment: By the way: SqlCommand also has an `ExecuteScalar` method, to get just a single value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)

```
using (var context = new YourDatabaseEntities())
{
    var elements = (from c in context.YourTable where c.TaskId == taskId select c);
}
```

Comment: Or you can use LINQ to SQL, if you just want to run simple SQL queries and SPs

Comment: Can you elaberate on the benefits of this over Method 1. They essentially follow the same pattern. (A using statement, followed by an Sql like statement to aquire the data)

Comment: Yes both approach have nearly the same pattern, but with EF you don't inject your parameters directly in your query, it will also manage your DB Null values by using nullable properties, and some other advantages !

Answer (score 3):

Method 1 looks far better in my opinion.

Method 2 does have a few things you can do to cut down on the code but you would only want Method 2 if you wanted greater control of your connection.

As Djoul6 suggested you can use Entity Framework as well. I prefer EF over everything else. Even though it takes a slight performance hit it is worth it for the amount of code you can push out in such a short space of time and the added security (SQL injection) among many other things.